# template is not loading in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

iam working on angulatjs uirouter.The code contains 2 states say home and new and when i click on any of these links the state & url changess.But the problem is the template corresponding to those state is not loading.

here is my code

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",['restangular','ui.router']);
app.config(['RestangularProvider',function(RestangularProvider){
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:9999')
}])
app.config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
   $stateProvider.
      state('home',{
          url:'/home',
          templateUrl:'/view/home.html'
      })
      .state('next',{
          url:'new',
          templateUrl:'/view/new.html'
      })
}])
```

html

```
<a ui-sref='home'>
    home
</a>
<a ui-sref='next'>
    new
</a>
```

i don't know what the problem is? can anyone help me?..

Comment: Is there an error appearing on console? Maybe the template files are not referenced properly, or not served properly by your local server.

Comment: there are no error on console. when i remove the template file from the /view location it shows an error  like  GET http://localhost:9999/view/new.html 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you missed the `ui-view` in order to let the template get plugged in

```
<a ui-sref='home'>
  home
</a>
<a ui-sref='next'>
  new
</a>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Comment: Now the new template is loding below the old contents. Is there any way to load new template by replacing the old one?

Comment: If you'll start your application containing a default template, and you'll put those ui-sref links inside this default template, the default/'old' content will be changed when you navigate between the states.